# how to disable/enable dragging, zooming and change the cursor in Google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how can i disable/enable dragging, zooming in a 'map' object. also how can i change the cursor to for example a plus sign and then change it back to default.

I have tried these but doesn't work:

```
 map.google.maps.MapOptions.disableDoubleClickZoom = true;
map.google.maps.MapOptions.draggable = false;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options how to set map options:

```
map = new google.maps.Map({ draggable : false }); // upon initialization
map.setOptions({ draggable : false }); // or in runtime
```

- to disable the zoom you may try to use `minZoom` and `maxZoom` options (set them to the same value as `zoom` option), or you may try to set `zoomControl` to false,
- to change the cursor which is displayed over the map use `draggableCursor` option, i.e. `map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'crosshair' });`. To change back to default just set it to `null`: `map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: null });`.

Comment: This still leaves the mousewheel zoom enabled. To also prevent that use the option scrollwheel: false => map.setOptions({ scrollwheel: false });

Comment: @Larzan I think this is covered by my point *"to disable the zoom you may try to use minZoom and maxZoom options"*, isn't it?

Comment: @TMS unfortunately it is not if you do not set the zoom explicitly. In my case i had a number of points and used 'fitBounds' to adapt the zoom to contain all markers. That means i do not know the actual zoom used and can't use min and max :) so scrollwheel: false was the only option that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the most of the actions over the map use:

```
    mapOptions: {
    disableDefaultUI : true,
    clickableIcons: false,
    gestureHandling: 'none',
    draggableCursor: 'arrow' //use the arrow default pointer ;)
  }
```